# How/where to load data which a certain class needs injected into it

Tags: php, dependency-injection

To make code more testable I have learned to inject an objects dependencies into it and I realized I was not doing that in my `Config` and `Router` classes.

The `Config` object loads up the application configuration settings from a php file and the `Router` loads up custom routes from a php file.

I want to inject the configuration settings into the `Config` object when it is instantiated and inject the custom routes into the `Router` object when it is instantiated.

These objects are created in a small dependency injection container so would the code for loading the data go in there? Or does it make sense to have some sort of loader class which can load data from php files and encapsulate any logic/error checking?